# Apollo GraphQL local state getting undefined with useQuery on refreshing app

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I get my data on the first initial load, and then if I refresh my app, my data becomes undefined. Only when I change the default state, I get the initial load data again.

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache();
cache.writeData({
  data: {
    apples: {
      sets: [],
      __typename: 'Apples',
    },
  },
});
```

In one of my components, I have:

```
const {data, loading, error} = useQuery(appleSets);
console.log('local state', data, loading, error, useQuery(appleSets));

const appleSets = gql`
  query {
    apples @client {
      sets
    }
  }
`;
```

On the first load, I get my console logged with apple data and the sets empty array, but then when I refresh, it becomes `undefined`. If I change the default values, the initial load gets data again. Why does this undefined?

Comment: `data` will always be initially undefined, even if it's available in the cache. With that in mind, does it *stay* undefined or is your concern only that it's initially undefined? It would also be helpful to know how you're running this app in development? Is this CRA? Next.js?

Comment: @DanielRearden I'm running with React Native. The thing is that my data shows up on initial load. After I make the first change in my default values, it will be shown up in console log. But if I make a change somewhere else (it refreshes the app), then the data becomes undefined.

Comment: @hellomello you need to persist your cash using react ative Asyncstorage. https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-cache-persist

Comment: @abdelhedihlel ohhh okay thanks! i think that's what worked.